# How to contain FlatButton UI with child Image?

Tags: flutter

I want to have my image like the size of the container FlatButton

Here is my code

```
child: FlatButton(
     child: canRoll
           ? Image.asset( '/images/wRoll.png', fit: BoxFit.contain,)
           : Image.asset('/images/wNoRoll.png',fit: BoxFit.contain,),
```

Is there away to make the size of my image bigger? or responsive to my FlatButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was just add the image as decoration and set FlatButton child as null and it's looking great.

```
Container(
   width: widget.squareSize,
   height: widget.squareSize,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
        image: _canRoll
          ? checkRollDiceImage(_mySet)
          : checkNoRollDiceImage(_mySet))),
        child: Tooltip(
           message: 'Roll the dice',
           child: FlatButton(
             child: null,
               onPressed: !_canRoll
                    ? null
                    : () {
                     playDiceRollAudio();

                    },
                 ),
             ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Container(child: ConstrainedBox(
constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
child: FlatButton(
         onPressed: null,
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
         child: canRoll ? Image.asset('images/wRoll.png')
                        : Image.asset('images/wNoRoll.png')
       ) //FlatButton
    ) //ConstrainedBox
 ) //Container
```

Setting the padding to zero should help.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?  If so, I'd greatly appreciate if you'd select the answer and give my answer an upvote. if not, please let me know how I can improve it.